# Side by Side two navbar bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

How is possible I put two navbars side-by-side using Twitter's bootstrap.

[image: navbars]

I want the sorting navbar on right side of filtering navbar.

Comment: Do you need them in the same navbar? You can set two columns and have them side by side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to declare their width and then give them a value of `float: left`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/KY2Pr/27/

```
.navbar {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}
```

Fluid width mobile friendly

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/KY2Pr/28/

```
.navbar {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: how the two navbars will behavior in different display sizes ? in mobile ?

Comment: The nav bars will go below each other on smaller screen sizes. Unless you give them a width of `50%` then they will just scale down accordingly - see my edit.